# django static folder is not served in apache2

Tags: python, django, apache

I have inherited a django application (1.7) and I am supposed to install it on Apache2. Everything runs fine when I do runserver from command prompt but as deploy to apache2/mod_wsgi.

I am pretty sure the STATICFILES_DIRS has been set correctly.

The settings.py is like below:

```
"""
Django settings for sampleapp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""    
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))    

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'tf07wvjy+#g&&#s$spi34_c-jno^8_cb0bw=*dx2ni2+w6x-(h'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.36',  'localhost']    

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 'south',
    'CordeliaHanelBackend',
    'tastypie',
    'StudioHanel',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'CordeliaHanelBackend.urls'

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
#     '/var/www/CordeliaHanelBackend-master/StudioHanel/templates/StudioHanel',
# )

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/var/www/CordeliaHanelBackend-master/StudioHanel/templates/StudioHanel','CordeliaHanelBackend/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'CordeliaHanelBackend.wsgi.application'    

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }    
}    

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]    

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'    
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True    
USE_TZ = True    

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

    '/var/www/CordeliaHanelFrontend-master/www/dist/',
        # '/var/www/CordeliaHanelFrontend-master/www/app',
        # '/var/www/CordeliaHanelBackend-master/StudioHanel/static',
    )

# STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/CordeliaHanelFrontend-master/www/app'    

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

# DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = '/var/www/CordeliaHanelFrontend-master/www/app'    

SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER = {
'default': 'south.db.sqlite3'
}
```

and here is the apache2 configuration site-available file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

WSGIDaemonProcess sampleapp python-path=/var/www/CordeliaHanelBackend-master:/var/www/CordeliaHanelBackend-master/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup sampleapp
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/CordeliaHanelBackend-master/CordeliaHanelBackend/wsgi.py

    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf 

# EDIT

Alias /static /var/www/CordeliaHanelFrontend-master/www/dist/
<Directory /var/www/CordeliaHanelFrontend-master/www/dist/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: So where is the line in that Apache configuration that will handle static files at the static URL? And why have you commented out the definition of STATIC_ROOT in the Django settings?

Comment: Ok I did the above edit and added         Alias /static /var/www/CordeliaHanelFrontend-master/www/dist/
    <Directory /var/www/CordeliaHanelFrontend-master/www/dist/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

Comment: What about the STATIC_ROOT I just don't understand its role. I googled it says it is useful only in debug mode. So I would say for production only apache config file is enough for serving static files. Correct?

Comment: No. STATIC_ROOT is the place that Django will put the files when you run collectstatic, and therefore the place that you should point that Apache directory configuration at.

Comment: how is the one defined by Directory apache conf. tag different from what is defined by settings.py (ie. STATICFILES_DIRS)?? thx

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS is the *source* of your app's static files. When you run collectstatic, Django collects your files and those built-in and third-party apps - including the admin - and puts them in STATIC_ROOT. So your Apache configuration should point at STATIC_ROOT; otherwise you won't get any JS or CSS in the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define path to your project in apache's configuration as:

```
<Directory /path/my/project/www/xyz.com>  # In your case: /var/www/CordeliaHanelBackend-master
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```